# Exclude records on manytomany relationship in Django

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models with a many to many relationship as shown:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total_weeks = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='admin_id')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    season_set = models.ManyToManyField(Season, through='LeagueSeason')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
        super(League, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class LeagueSeason(models.Model):
    GANADOR = 1
    RESULTADO_EXACTO = 2

    Type = (
        (GANADOR, 'Escoger ganador'),
        (RESULTADO_EXACTO, 'Escoger resultado exacto'),
    )

    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='leagues_set')
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='season_set')
    season_type = models.IntegerField(choices=Type, default=GANADOR)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "leagues_seasons"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'League {} - {}'.format(self.league.name, self.season.name)
```

My season serializers are like this:

```
class LeagueSeasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LeagueSeason
        fields = [
            'league_id',
            'season_type'
        ]

class SeasonsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    season_set = LeagueSeasonSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Season
        fields = '__all__'
```

All is good and fine, but when I make a request `/league/7/seasons` I get this result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "season_set": [
            {
                "league_id": 7,
                "season_type": 1
            },
            {
                "league_id": 8,
                "season_type": 2
            }
        ],
        "name": "2020 Season",
        "total_weeks": 21,
        "active": true,
        "created_at": "2020-10-08T11:40:26.131187-05:00",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-08T11:40:26.131209-05:00"
    },
    ...
]
```

The serialized data is correct, but as I have the same season on two different leagues, I'm getting the related manytomany results with all the leagues the season is on. Is there a way that I can exclude the related results to only return the records related to the league? The set would would remove the related "league_id = 8" because I only requested the ones from 7, and end like so?

```
        ...
        "season_set": [
            {
                "league_id": 7,
                "season_type": 1
            }
        ],
        ...
```

My view calling the serializer is this:

```
class SeasonsView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        try:
            league = League.objects.get(id=id)
            leagues = request.user.league_set.all()
            if(league not in leagues):
                return Response({'message': 'User is not enrolled in league.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                seasons = league.season_set.filter(active=True)
                serializer = SeasonsSerializer(seasons, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)
        except League.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'League not found.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

And my url.py is calling the view like this:

```
...
path('league/<int:id>/seasons/', SeasonsView.as_view()),
...
```

Comment: can you provide the views and urls?

Comment: @zhivko-zaikov edited the post to show the view and urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was add a serializer method field on the related serializer and search for the specificic record.

```
class SeasonsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    settings = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Season
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_settings(self, obj):
        settings = LeagueSeason.objects.filter(season__id=obj.id, league__id=self.context['league_id'])
        serializer = LeagueSeasonSerializer(settings, many=True).data
        return serializer
```

For getting the league_id I sent a context variable in the view like this:

```
serializer = SeasonsSerializer(seasons, many=True, context={'league_id': league_id})
```

I got the resulting json like I wanted but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it. If somebody has another way to do it, please let me know.